# Bitter Cucumbers

Tags: flavor, cutting, cucumbers

I was watching a cooking show and the chef made the comment that if you use a large basic cucumber (not hot house, persian, kirbys, english, etc.) before you peel it, cut off about half an inch of the ends and rub them on the opposite sides, then throw the cut off ends away and peel as usual.  I normally buy persian, hot house, english or other types but I purchased some of these larger cucumbers.  I did what the chef said and they were great.  I did this a few times, and I take my time picking out long, slender, firm, green fresh cucumbers.  I started buying these when I thought the price was right but then I thought taste them first to see if they were good to start off with.  They were.  I pickled about 4 gallons of persian cucumbers last week and tasted the ones I thought might be bad, they were and tried the trick.  Did not work.  All cucumbers were USA products and grown in California.  My friend brought me some big cucumbers last night and we tried the trick.  Well, she eats anything but it did not work.  Has anyone heard of this trick or knows why it works sometimes?  Maybe the age, the girth of the cucumber, not straight or even in size, any ideas?

Comment: Just a link to the trick : http://lifehacker.com/remove-a-cucumber-s-bitterness-by-chopping-and-rubbing-1632826153

Comment: You peel the cucumber before eating it?

Comment: Thanks to the link and yes I have to peel.  My Mom is elderly and her digestive tract is bad.  I peel everything and process and cut teeney tiny most hard foods for her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are supposed to do it until white milky stuff comes out, but I never had a bitter cucumber, and I have even grown them too big and old and yellowing before picking, like the size of a big fat baseball bat. I just peel and scoop the seeds out of the cucumber just like it was any other melon and the flesh tastes just fine.

Comment: You have made my day...but really... as big as a fat baseball bat? It tasted good?  What on earth did you do to it?  My Dad use to grow veges and once in a great while we would get zuchinni that looked like watermelons.  They were awful no matter what we tried to do to them.

Comment: I didn't do anything except harvest it late. They keep growing until you pick them or they start to rot. When they get older the skins yellows and toughens and the seeds get firmer like melon seeds are supposed to. You see, a cucumber is normally harvested before its ripe, that's when it's good to eat. If you let it ripen, you can't use it the same way anymore because it's become a ripened melon at that point and you have to treat it as a melon